# Change character of a string in shell script

Tags: shell

What is the best way to change a character in a string in shell script ?

I have the following variable:

```
A="2017-03-16 18:00:00"
```

I would like to change it for "2017-03-16 18:00:01" (adding +1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to *Change character of a string in shell script* as mentionned in your title, you can use parameter expansion:

```
$ A="2017-03-16 18:00:00"
$ echo ${A%0}1
2017-03-16 18:00:01
```

If you want to add 1 second to a date, then [Hunter McMillen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42858763/3266847) does the job.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `date` command to add 1 second to a specific date:

```
$ date -d "2017-03-16 18:00:00+1 seconds"
Thu Mar 16 13:00:01 EDT 2017
```

(Note that this converted to local timezone EST)

Incorporated into your script, that would be:

```
#!/bin/sh 

A="2017-03-16 18:00:00"
date -d "$A+1 seconds"
```

Comment: I would like to do something like that A[18]=1 like in C, for instance.

Comment: I was able to accomplish that like that echo $A | sed s/./1/19.

Comment: That isn't the question you asked.

Comment: This was not what I asked, but I found out your solution was better. Thank you!